# JQuery: Loading data from database and inserting it to select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've three selects, which looks like this:

```
<select name="nick">
<?php foreach ($chars as $char):?>
<option value='<?php echo $char['name'] ?>'><?php echo $char['name'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<select name='faction' disabled>
<option value='ally'>Alliance</option>
<option value='horde'>Horde</option>
</select>
<select name='class' id="class" disabled>
<option value='1'>Warrior</option>
<option value='2'>Paladin</option>
<option value='3'>Hunter</option>
<option value='4'>Rogue</option>
<option value='5'>Priest</option>
<option value='6'>Death Knight</option>
<option value='7'>Shaman</option>
<option value='8'>Mage</option>
<option value='9'>Warlock</option>
<option value='10'>Druid</option>
</select>
```

$chars:

```
$chars = array(0 => array("name" => "Solock",
                          "level" => "80",
                          "class" => "9"),
               1 => array("name" => "Emmorts",
                          "level" => "80",
                          "class" => "3"),
               2 => array("name" => "Ghom",
                          "level" => "80",
                          "class" => "2"),
);
$json = json_encode($chars);
```

JSON array:

```
[
{"name":"Solock","level":"80","class":"9"},
{"name":"Emmorts","level":"80","class":"3"},
{"name":"Ghom","level":"80","class":"2"}
]
```

JSON object:

```
{
"0":{"name":"Solock","level":"80","class":"9"},
"1":{"name":"Emmorts","level":"80","class":"3"},
"2":{"name":"Ghom","level":"80","class":"2"}
}
```

Is it possible, to everytime when I change [name=nick] option, other selects would select with the data from JSON object or array (if I choose "Ghom", it'd select Alliance, and Death knight)? How?

Thank you.

Comment: Your select elements are nick, faction and class, but the JSON string contains information about the nick, **level** and class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - on the server and based on the database entries - create a JSON string:

```
{
    "Solock": ["ally", "9"],
    "Emmorts": ["ally", "3"],
    "Ghom": ["ally", "6"]
}
```

Next, on the client, load that JSON string into a JavaScript object. Now, you can use jQuery and that object:

```
var $selectNick = $('select[name=nick]'),
    $selectFaction = $('select[name=faction]'),
    $selectClass = $('select[name=class]');

$selectNick.change(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    $selectFaction.val( json[value][0] );
    $selectClass.val( json[value][1] );
});
```

(Here, the `json` variable is the object created from the JSON string.)

***Working demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/tgeVh/

Comment: How do I create a JSON string? :)

Comment: @Tom You use PHP to read the database and create a string. I cannot help you with that since I don't know PHP and/or mySQL. You may ask another question...

Comment: I've updated my question, could you add a jsfiddle demo with my JSON string structure? Thank you

Comment: The JSON string in the demo does not match what is in the edited question. Either the PHP code will need to be changed to index by the name, as in the demo, or the HTML/JavaScript will need to be changed to select the Nth subset of the JS object.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, I can write a transformation function which transforms the original object into the form that I use. But first the OP has to clarify if he needs the faction or level information...

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. I recommend that you check out the [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) PHP function. You should be able to use that function to encode the `$chars` variable into [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). You can then use the [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method of jQuery to create a JavaScript object based on the JSON string.

If you do not need to use `$char['name']` as the value for the `select`, then you might want to consider using indices (beginning at 0) to easily reference the JavaScript object with.